# Как переопределить метод в DjangoFilterBackend?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-filter

Я в доках смотрел, но так и не смог разобраться, чтобы это помогло в моей ситуации.
Есть вьюшка для списка объектов с фильтрацией.

```
class MenuLinksView(generics.ListAPIView):
    queryset = MenuLink.active_objects.all()
    serializer_class = MenuSerializer
    filter_backends = [DjangoFilterBackend]
    filterset_fields = ['lang_menu_link']
```

И получается так, что стоит задача - сделать язык, загружаемый сайтом, по умолчанию русский. Думаю здесь нужно переопределить метод, если к примеру в качестве фильтра запрос ничего не принимает, то сайт загружается русский, если уже поступает какая-то фильтрация, то загружается сайт по той фильтрации, которая была выбрана. Ещё DjangoFilterBackend использует для фильтрации подобное ?lang_menu_link=Ru, а когда сайт загружается по умолчанию русский, то такого быть не должно и поэтому скорее всего в переопределении метода фильтрации нужно это как-то указать. К примеру, если фильтрации нет, то MenuLink.objects.filter(lang_menu_link='Ru'), ну что-то примерно такое. Возможно для того, что мне нужно сделать следует вообще отказаться от DjangoFilterBackend и написать все вручную, но как это сделать я не знаю. Кто может с этим помочь?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

По итогу я просто переопределил метод get_queryset и сделал чтобы по умолчанию загружался русский.

```
def get_queryset(self):
        query = self.request.query_params.get('lang_menu_link')
        if query:
            queryset = MenuLink.active_objects.filter(lang_menu_link=query)
        else:
            queryset = MenuLink.active_objects.filter(lang_menu_link='Ru')

        return queryset
```